# Undefined references to libm symbols after upgrading Linux distro

Tags: c, gcc, linker, linker-errors

I upgraded my Linux distro from Pop OS 19.10 to 20.04, and it naturally included upgrades to glibc & co. Since then, I started getting linker errors for libm symbols like `__pow_finite`.

Unfortunately, the code that references these symbols is a static library (libWithPowFiniteRef.a in the redacted snippet below) with third-party proprietary code. I don't have access to source.

I checked `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6` using `nm`. The symbol is there:

```
nm -gD /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
...
0000000000010e00 W powf64x
00000000000471f0 i __powf_finite
000000000002ed90 i __pow_finite
0000000000010e00 W powl
0000000000019860 T __powl_finite
...
```

So I can't explain the errors:

```
g++  -o ./media_tests -Wl,--verbose -Wl,--start-group @"./media_tests.rsp"  -ldl -lpthread -lrt ../../third_party/other.so  ../../third_party/redacted/lib/Linux/x64/libWithPowFiniteRef.a -Wl,--end-group
...
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libm.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libm.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so succeeded
...
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libm.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libm.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so succeeded
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 succeeded
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
...
/usr/bin/ld:../../third_party/redacted/lib/Linux/x64/redacted.a(redacted.o): in function `RedactedX':
redacted1.c:(.text+0xbb0): undefined reference to `__pow_finite'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../third_party/redacted/lib/Linux/x64/redacted.a(redacted.o): in function `RedactedY':
redacted2.c:(.text+0x7ad9): undefined reference to `__pow_finite'
/usr/bin/ld: redacted.c:(.text+0x8c74): undefined reference to `__pow_finite'
/usr/bin/ld: link errors found, deleting executable `./media_tests'
```

Maybe we the solution is to request a new static lib from the vendor, but I would like to understand why.

Comment: Does adding `-lm` to the command line help?

Comment: Also see [here](https://github.com/google/filament/issues/2146).  It sounds like you either need to recompile (or request a new vendor library) or, if that's not an option, link with the old libraries.  Or perhaps you could grab the source for just those functions and build your own compatibility library.

Comment: What happens if you add `-lm` *after* that static library in the gcc command line?

Comment: @TomKarzes: You hit it in the head. I can actually repro the problem by building a simple static library that uses `pow` with `-ffast-math` in an older distro (using Docker), and trying to link to it in the newer distro. I also inspected the same library built in the newer distro, using the same flags: `__pow_finite` is not referenced anymore, just the vanilla `pow`. I was able to work around the issue by converting the static library into a shared library using the old distro. I was able to use the resulting `.so` in the new distro. You should submit an answer so I can give you proper credit.